Connecting to a DevContainer running on a remote computer on the same network
In a nutshell, I have two computers in a virtual local network. I need to connect to a DevContainer present in the "Computer A" from "Computer B", so I can remotely develop.
While theoretically SSH on the DevContainer (a container in essence) should work, all tries and workarounds have been futile with different type of errors each time.
Is there a way to connect remotely?

Sorry, two computers, virtual network? Can you please create a diagram of how that works, how the virtual network correlates to the physical network, and how the containers connect to both the physical and the virtual network?
